# Getting a NotSerializableException even though all the objects I'm sending are Serializable

Tags: java, serializable

Okay, so I have this class which extends JFrame and I'm basically trying to create this JPanel which takes in information and sends out an "Event" object when the Submit button is pressed. Everything seems to be working, except that when I press submit, it tells me my client needs to be serializable... (the Client class is a basic class that opens a connection to a specific port. It works, I've tested it and it's not the problem). I have Serialized all the objects I would be sending. I don't understand why I am getting a NotSerializableException. Been trying to figure this out for hours now. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public class WindowGameActual extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private final static int PORT = 11114; 

private GameState game;

public WindowClient connection;

JPanel container;


JTextArea description;
JTextField difficulty; 
JCheckBox check4;
JCheckBox check6;
JCheckBox check8;
JCheckBox check12;
JCheckBox check20;

JCheckBox agl;
JCheckBox str;
JCheckBox mana;


public class WindowClient extends Client 
{
    public WindowClient(String host) throws IOException
    {
        super(host, PORT);
    }


    protected void messageReceived(Object message) 
    {
        if(message instanceof GameState)
          {
             game = (GameState) message;
             container.repaint();
          }

    }
} //end WindowClient


public WindowGameActual(String host) 
{

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    game = new GameState();

    try {
        connection = new WindowClient(host);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     container = new JPanel();
     GridLayout gridC = new GridLayout(3, 1);
     container.setLayout(gridC);

     CurrentEventPanel curEvt = new CurrentEventPanel(game);
     curEvt.updateEvent(game);
     container.add(curEvt);

//       ControlPanel eventControl = new ControlPanel(host);
//       container.add(eventControl);

     GridLayout outerPanel = new GridLayout(4, 1);
     JPanel control = new JPanel();
     control.setLayout(outerPanel);

     JPanel layer1 = new JPanel();

     JLabel eDescription = new JLabel("Describe Event:");
     layer1.add(eDescription);

     description = new JTextArea("");
     description.setEditable(true);
     description.setColumns(17);
     layer1.add(description);

     control.add(layer1);

     JPanel layer2 = new JPanel();

     JLabel eDifficulty = new JLabel("Event Difficulty (integers only):");
     layer2.add(eDifficulty);

     difficulty = new JTextField("");
     difficulty.setEditable(true);
     difficulty.setColumns(2);
     layer2.add(difficulty);

     JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
     submit.addActionListener(this);
     submit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(74, 22));
     layer2.add(submit);

     control.add(layer2);


     JPanel layer3 = new JPanel();

     JLabel dice = new JLabel("dice:   ");
     layer3.add(dice);

     JLabel d4 = new JLabel("d4");
     check4 = new JCheckBox();
     layer3.add(d4);
     layer3.add(check4);

     JLabel d6 = new JLabel("d6");
     check6 = new JCheckBox();
     layer3.add(d6);
     layer3.add(check6);

     JLabel d8 = new JLabel("d8");
     check8 = new JCheckBox();
     layer3.add(d8);
     layer3.add(check8);

     JLabel d12 = new JLabel("d12");
     check12 = new JCheckBox();
     layer3.add(d12);
     layer3.add(check12);

     JLabel d20 = new JLabel("d20");
     check20 = new JCheckBox();
     layer3.add(d20);
     layer3.add(check20);

     control.add(layer3);

     JPanel layer4 = new JPanel();

     JLabel skills = new JLabel("Skills Required: ");
     layer4.add(skills);

     JLabel strLabel = new JLabel("Str");
     str = new JCheckBox();
     layer4.add(strLabel);
     layer4.add(str);

     JLabel aglLabel = new JLabel("Agl");
     agl = new JCheckBox();
     layer4.add(aglLabel);
     layer4.add(agl);

     JLabel manaLabel = new JLabel("Mana");
     mana = new JCheckBox();
     layer4.add(manaLabel);
     layer4.add(mana);

     control.add(layer4);

     container.add(control);
     //         setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));

     UserStatPanel stats = new UserStatPanel(game);
     stats.updateStatPanel(game);
     container.add(stats);


    add(container);
    setVisible(true);
}


public class Event implements Serializable
{
    public String eventDescription ;
    public String diff ;

    public boolean strChecked ;
    public boolean aglChecked ;
    public boolean manaChecked ;

    public boolean d4checked ;
    public boolean d6checked ;
    public boolean d8checked ;
    public boolean d12checked ;
    public boolean d20checked;

    public Event()
    {
        eventDescription = description.getText();
        diff = difficulty.getText();
        strChecked = str.isSelected();
        aglChecked = agl.isSelected();
        manaChecked = mana.isSelected();
        d4checked = check4.isSelected();
        d6checked = check6.isSelected();
        d8checked = check8.isSelected();
        d12checked = check12.isSelected();
        d20checked = check20.isSelected();
    }


}
Event nEvent;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
{
    String cmd = evt.getActionCommand();
    if(cmd.equals("Submit"))
    {
        nEvent = new Event();
        connection.send(nEvent); 
    }


}



}
```

Here is my Error Message (it's abnormally short):

```
Client send thread terminated by IOException: java.io.NotSerializableException: testGame.WindowGameActual$WindowClient
Client send thread terminated.
Client receive thread terminated.
Hub receive thread terminated by IOException: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: testGame.WindowGameActual$WindowClient
```

If you need any of my other classes let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Exception says `testGame.WindowGameActual$WindowClient` is not serializable. Pls check `Client` class whether it is serializable. If possible post `Client` class also..

Comment: Also, it is not a good practice to serialize objects that extend swing components or contain swing component

Comment: Mark all those swing fields as `transient` and you'll be freed of this problem.

Comment: marking certain fields as `transient ` may give some other functional issues whether you de-serialize the classes.. be careful

Comment: Can you show us the code where the exception occurs and what you are passing to the writeObject?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Marking fields as `transient` should only be done after you have thought carefully about exactly what it is that you are serializing. Blindly throwing `transient` around without understanding *why* a field is being unexpectedly serialized is a recipe for bizarre bugs in the future.

Comment: @CameronSkinner I didn't tell OP to blindly mark every field as `transient`, just those who are `swing` components.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: That's correct: You told the OP to blindly mark every Swing component field as transient without trying to understand why the code is attempting to serialize those fields in the first place. Misuse of `transient` can create subtle and hard-to-find bugs, so don't use it lightly.

Comment: @CameronSkinner so in the other hand you're suggesting that serializing swing components won't have any downside effect at all?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: No, of course not. Where did you get that idea? I'm saying that if you see a field being serialized that you don't expect then you need to think about your data structures and see if you can factor them more sensibly. Your serializable data structures should contain only the data you want serialized. If you find that a Swing component gets serialized when you don't want it then your data structure is probably wrong.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: It's **OK** to use `transient` when appropriate. But know when it's appropriate and when it's not.

Comment: @CameronSkinner I know when its appropriate and when isn't. Sorry, didn't read OP's whole code. Looks like the problem is about having the `Event` class as inner class of `WindowGameActual`, which resolves in a bad class design...

Answer (score 4):

The exception message clearly says that WindowClient is not Serializable. The most reasonable way to fix it is to make Client (which WindowClient extends) Serializable

Comment: This is only fixing the symptoms, not the root cause, though. Most likely not what the OP had in mind.

Comment: That's not the most reasonable way to fix it. Does it make sense for `Client` to implement `Serializable`? Are you going to wind up serializing the whole GUI if you do so? If so, that's going to be slow and take up a lot of bandwidth if you're trying to send messages across the wire.

Comment: I tried serializing Client, but then it wanted me to serialize a method inside Client and then it wanted me to serialize Java.io.inputstream which didn't seem like a good idea to me

Answer (score 3):

Your class `Event` is an inner class of `WindowGameActual`, thus whenever your try to serialize an instance of Event, the enclosing instance of WindowGameActual and all its fields will be serialized as well.

Solution: Do not use inner classes unless really appropriate, promote the Event class to its own file.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Mark **what** as transient? The problem in this case is the implicit outer `this`. How can you mark that as transient? See my comment above about understanding what you are serializing and why.

Comment: This resolved it! Thank you so much! Definitely will keep this in mind haha.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at XStream http://x-stream.github.io/ it has the same functionality as serializing/deserializing, except you are dealing with XML. There is no need for a class to implement Serializable. This will solve all of your problems without any work arounds.